# re.search multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing the script line by line to find the following pattern "print("xxxx") or "LOG.info("xxxx").

1. When the below pattern is executed, it matches all the line starts with print
   `SeacrhOutput = re.search(r'print\(((.*?)\))' ,line)`
2. however, following error was observed - `sre_constants.error: bad escape \L at position 5` when the LOG.info was added to the pattern `re.search(r'print\|LOG.info\(((.*?)\))' ,line)`

Comment: I think you did not post the actual regex. However, it looks like you want something like `r'\b(?:print|LOG\.info)\((.*?)\)'`. Note it will fail if your log/print string literal contains another `)`.

Comment: I have mentioned the actual regex - i wanted to capture all the information present after the "print' or "LOG.info" word

Comment: None of your regexps can throw the *`sre_constants.error: bad escape \L at position 5`* error

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?:print|LOG\.info)\((.*?)\)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/VV9Wpf/1/). The expression will match `print` or `LOG.info` with `(` after them, and then capture any zero or more characters into a group up to the leftmost `)`.

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    print                    'print'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LOG                      'LOG'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    info                     'info'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```